# Field type date bad formatting

Tags: 8, nodes, datetime

i have a strange issue with a field "date".
First i save it programatically this way :

```
$now = new \DateTime();
$node->set('field_paiement_date' => DrupalDateTime::createFromTimestamp($now->getTimestamp());
$node->save();
```

Then when i come on the content type in the back office i've got this value :[image]

And finally when i dump the field in question i got this value : [image]

My current timezone is 'Pacific/Noumea', so the correct value i want to show to the users is the one when i dump the field. What is the best way to do that ?

Regards,

Comment: You've stored the time in your local time, but you need to store it in UTC, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/246668

Comment: Okay now it's works thank you !
I have an other issue, in my twig template when i want to use the date filter, it always print as UTC but not at my current timezone ...

Comment: ... then you print the raw database value. If you output the date field normally, that is by a field formatter configured in the display mode of the content type, then it should print the date in the current time zone. If you need to print the date field directly in twig, then use the `date` property, which is a formattable date object instead of the `value` property which is the raw data.

Answer (score 2):

Datetime values in storage are UTC, if you are storing datetime values by your own, you have to pay attention on this and display datetimes to users considering your timezone ('Pacific/Noumea' probably declared in your php.ini or user's timezone present in user profile).

Storing `2018-05-02T08:23:25` as your current datetime in caledonia in database is a nonsense considering timezone, because the format `DateTimeItemInterface::DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT` do not include timezone.

```
$date = strtotime($node->field_paiement_date->value);
\Drupal::service('date.formatter')
  ->format($date, 'custom', 'Y-m-d H:i:s', drupal_get_user_timezone());
\Drupal::service('date.formatter')
  ->format($date, 'custom', 'Y-m-d H:i:s', 'Pacific/Noumea');
```